# Dual booting windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 - I can boot into W7, but I only hear sound, no display

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I know there are lots of dual boot questions on Askubuntu, but can't find reference to the specific issue I am having:

When booting into windows, I can hear the Windows startup music, and I can enter my password and hear the log in sound, but the screen stays blank, or rather it retains the same purple of the grub screen.

I have a Thinkpad x250. Windows 7 was (is) installed. To install Ubuntu I went through the following steps:
1. In W7, I had two partitions, with D: allocated to user files - I moved my user from D: to C: 
2. with the Ubuntu 14.04 live USB, launched gparted, and 1) deleted second partition, 2) resized windows system partition, 3) created an ext4 partition with the free space
3. installed Ubuntu using the new partition
4. rebooted, checked that Ubuntu worked. All ok. 
5. rebooted, chose W7 in grub -- some message about checking the disk, at some point it restarts
6. boot into windows, problem appears: all the windows sounds are there, but no display besides the Ubuntu purple, I can type in my password and know I am logged in judging from the log in sound

EDIT: I can get into Windows normally if I do this: just after I select W7 in the grub menu, I press (and keep pressed) F8, which gives me a list of options. I select 'start Windows normally' and everything is ok. Good, so I have a way to get into Windows not, but ideally I would like to avoid going through this F8 routine when I want to start W7.

Comment: You may need to try boot-repair to fix this. Are you able to see the Windows partition from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for Ubuntu with a live CD. Check the option for "Repair Windows Files".